How to use list comprehension in the Sieve of Atkin algorithm?
I am writing a Python program to find a list of prime numbers.
I wrote it using the Sieve of Eratosthenes:
def Eratosthenes(n:int) -> list[int]:
   if n <= 2:
      return []
   l = list(range(3,n,2))
   for i in l:
      if i == 0:
         continue
      if i*i > n:
         break
      for j in range(i//2-1+i,n//2-1,i):
         l[j] = 0
   return [2]+[i for i in l if i]

Then I heard that the Sieve of Atkin is way faster, so I wrote that version too:
import math

def Atkin(n:int) -> set[int]:
   s1 = {1,13,17,29,37,41,49,53}
   s2 = {7,19,31,43}
   s3 = {11,23,47,59}
   sq = {i*i for i in range(1,math.isqrt(n)+1)}
   l = [2,3,5]
   for x in sq:
      for y in sq:
         txpy = 3*x+y
         fxpy = txpy+x
         txmy = txpy-2*y
         if txpy < n and txpy%60 in s2:
            l.append(txpy)
         if fxpy < n and fxpy%60 in s1:
            l.append(fxpy)
         if txmy < n and txmy>0 and txmy%60 in s3:
            l.append(txmy)
   for i in l:
      if i == 0:
         continue
      for k,v in enumerate(l):
         if v <= i:
            continue
         if v % i == 0:
            l[k] = 0
   return {i for i in l if i > 0}

But I realized that I made a terrible code because this version is even slower than the one using the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I think one of the reasons might be that I used for + append instead of list comprehension. How could I improve this code?
I just found out that there is one extra problem: the Sieve of Atkin algorithm didn’t exclude 91 and a lot of other composite numbers. I have now fixed the algorithm.
My implementation was based on this YouTube video from 3:14 to 4:40. It wasn’t working.

It's asymptotically faster, which means you might not see the benefit of using it until you've identified the first, say, 10**20 prime numbers.

What n are you testing and how much time do they take?

I’m testing at n <= 10**7 because my computer says there’s memory issues. Besides, it takes more than one second for both algorithms already, there is no way that I can test n = 10**20 before the universe ends.

At n = 4*10⁶, the Sieve of Eratosthenes takes 0.4 s, the Sieve of Atkin takes 1.2 s

your implementation of atkin looks wrong: up to 200 it returns 91 and 143 and lots of duplicates. it doesn't return 199.

Before optimizing the code you should debug why e.g. 91 (not prime) is returned.

What is your implementation based on? I don't see a match with (for instance) the algorithm at Wikipedia. What is your source? Note that there are implementations in Python on this site
